# How do I group colours (Blue, Green, Purple, Red) from a csv file when the syntax (iePURPLE or PURPAL) is wrong?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

How do I group colours (Blue, Green, Purple, Red) from a csv file (50000 rows, example below) using Python when the syntax (ie. case, spelling - PURPLE or PURPAL) is wrong in several cases?  Thanks for any help you can give

```
Blue      5642
Purpal    5640
red       5610
BLUE      5583
Red       5541
green     5523
Purple    5503
Green     5491
RED       5467
......
```

Comment: Before grouping you must clean up your data i.e. get rid of PURPAL or any other similar corruptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to need to clean your data. Obviously this would be unique to whatever situation you data is in, but if you are trying to identify the misspelled color names then perhaps filter the DataFrame to show everything that is not Blue, Green, Purple, or Red.

You could do something like the following to identify the misfits and then figure out how to fix them.

```
df.Color = df.Color.str.lower()
colors = ['blue', 'red', 'purple', 'green']
misspellings = df.Color[~df.Color.isin(colors)].values
print(misspellings)
['purpal']
```

From there you could individually fix each entry or write something to intelligently fix them. It's up to you but once you've done that you can group as normal. To fix the entry or entries for 'purpal' you could do something like:

```
df.loc[df.Color == 'purpal', 'Color'] = 'purple'
```

Comment: Good answer!  Plus one. Hi @Grr

Comment: Thanks @Grr, much appreciated :)